# Is it possible to show the text of a textbox in anotherone referencing by ID? (QlikView)

Tags: text, reference, textbox, qlikview

I have a QlikView TextBox with some text like "This is a test and it is not working". 
Now I want to show the same text on another Sheet in another TextBox and it should always be the same.
So I want to reference the first TextBox, so that the text will be displayed in the second one.

Is it possible to refernce the TextBox by their ID? And if so, how can I realise this?

Answer (score 2):

Create your text box, right click on it, select "Copy to Clipboard -> Object", then go to whatever sheet you want the mirrored text box on (or same sheet if you want it on same), right click  and select "Paste Sheet Object As Link". I believe that will do what you want. You could always use a variable to accomplish this if you have a use for the text elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a linked object, which will mean that the content of one is mirrored on the other.

Set up a text box on one tab, then drag it onto a new tab whilst holding CTRL+SHIFT, you'll see a little chain link appear as you drag the object.

Now a change in one of these objects will reflected in *all* of the others.

Answer (score -2):

One component (Windows terminology) or widget (UNIX/X11 terminology) has precisely ONE physical manifestation; that's just a fundamental tenet of geometry management.

In order to have a textbox that "mirrors" another one, so to speak, you must retrieve the contents of the original and post it into the copy.  Make certain that you do this every time there's an event that either (a) modifies the text in the original textbox or (b) exposes--that is, renders visible when 'twas previously (partially) invisible--the secondary textbox.